# Simple Vigenere Cipher In Python

Tags: python, vigenere-cipher

I'm a relatively new programmer. I've made a simple Vigenere cipher program. It takes three arguments and acts on a file. I have made some of the steps more "explict" for myself by using more lists than I need to, rather than applying multiple "transformations" at a time. I would appreciate feedback on how this code would be written differently by people who know more than I do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# vigenere.py - This program has two modes, encrypt and decrypt. It takes
# three arguments: the mode('encrypt' or 'decrypt'), a keyword, and a
# filename to act upon. It is designed to work with lowercase letters.

from sys import argv
from itertools import cycle

# User specifies a mode, a key, and a file with argv arguments
def start():
    if len(argv) > 1:
        mode = argv[1]
        key = argv[2]
        plaintextFilename = argv[3]
    else:
        print('Please supply mode, key, and file as arguments.')
        exit()

    # Start the mode selected
    if mode == 'encrypt':
        encryptMode()
    elif mode == 'decrypt':
        decryptMode()
    else:
        print('Please supply \'encrypt\' or \'decrypt\' mode.')
        exit()


# Encryption Mode
def encryptMode():

    # Open the alpha plaintext file as an object
    alphaPlaintextFileObj = open(argv[3])

    # Create the ordinal plaintext data structure
    ordinalPlaintext = []

    # Populate the ordinal plaintext data structure
    for c in alphaPlaintextFileObj.read():
        if c == ' ':
            ordinalPlaintext.append(' ')
        else:
            o = ord(c) - 65
            ordinalPlaintext.append(o)

    # Create an ordinal ciphertext data structure
    ordinalCiphertext = []

    # Turn the key into an ordinal key where a = 1, etc.
    ordinalKey = []
    key = argv[2]
    for c in key:
        n = ord(c) - 96
        ordinalKey.append(n)

    # Populate the ordinalCiphertext structure with numbers shifted using the
    # ordinal key.
    for k, p in zip(cycle(ordinalKey), ordinalPlaintext):
        if p == ' ':
            ordinalCiphertext.append(' ')
        else:
            c = (k + p) % 25
            ordinalCiphertext.append(c)

    # Create the alpha ciphertext file
    alphaCiphertextFilename = argv[3] + '_encrypted'
    alphaCiphertextFileObj = open(alphaCiphertextFilename, 'w')

    # Populate the alpha ciphertext file
    for c in ordinalCiphertext:
        if c == ' ':
            alphaCiphertextFileObj.write(' ')
        else:
            l = chr(int(c) + 65)
            alphaCiphertextFileObj.write(l)

    # Save and close the plaintext and ciphertext files.
    alphaPlaintextFileObj.close()
    alphaCiphertextFileObj.close()

    # Print a message telling the user the operation is complete.
    print(f'{argv[3]} encrypted as {alphaCiphertextFilename}')

# Decryption Mode
def decryptMode():
    # Open the alpha ciphertext file as an object
    alphaCiphertextFileObj = open(argv[3])

    # Create the ordinal ciphertext data structure
    ordinalCiphertext = []

    # Populate the ordinal ciphertext data structure
    for c in alphaCiphertextFileObj.read():
        if c == ' ':
            ordinalCiphertext.append(' ')
        else:
            o = ord(c) - 97
            ordinalCiphertext.append(o)

    # Create the ordinal key
    ordinalKey = []
    key = argv[2]
    for c in key:
        n = ord(c) - 96
        ordinalKey.append(n)

    #Create the ordinal plaintext data structure
    ordinalPlaintext = []

    # Populate the ordinal plaintext data structure with the modular
    # difference of the ordinal ciphertext and the ordinal key
    for k, c in zip(cycle(ordinalKey), ordinalCiphertext):
        if c == ' ':
            ordinalPlaintext.append(' ')
        else:
            p = (c - k) % 25
            ordinalPlaintext.append(p)

    # Create the alpha plaintext file
    alphaPlaintextFilename = argv[3] + '_decrypted'
    alphaPlaintextFileObj = open(alphaPlaintextFilename, 'w')

    # Convert the ordinal plaintext to an alpha plaintext file,
    # 'filename_decrypted'
    for p in ordinalPlaintext:
        if p == ' ':
            alphaPlaintextFileObj.write(' ')
        else:
            l = chr(int(p) + 97)
            alphaPlaintextFileObj.write(l)

    # Save and close the ciphertext and plaintext files
    alphaCiphertextFileObj.close()
    alphaPlaintextFileObj.close()

    # Print a message telling the user the operation is complete
    print(f'{argv[3]} decrypted as {alphaPlaintextFilename}')

start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def start():
```

I'd call this function `main` as that's what it is generally called.

```
if mode == 'encrypt':
    encryptMode()
elif mode == 'decrypt':
    decryptMode()
```

Why not call this `encrypt` and `decrypt`? The methods to actually perform the encryption / decryption after all; you're not *setting* a mode.

```
alphaPlaintextFileObj = open(argv[3])
```

It seems to me that file handling can be perfectly split from the `encrypt` function, *especially* if you read in all the data before encryption happens anyway.

```
ordinalPlaintext = []
```

Why would you first convert the entire plaintext / ciphertext to ordinals? This can be done on a per-character base, preferably using a separate method. Then it also becomes easier to skip space and such, which you now have to handle twice.

Conversion to ordinals - or more precisely, indices within the Vigenere alphabet - is of course exactly what is needed, so that's OK.

```
o = ord(c) - 65
```

65 is an unexplained magic number, why not use `ord('a')` instead or use a constant with that value?

```
n = ord(c) - 96
```

Why is `A` a 1? What about `Z` in that case? And why do we suddenly use the uppercase character set?

```
for k, p in zip(cycle(ordinalKey), ordinalPlaintext):
```

Now this I like, it is very clear what is done here, and it is good use of Python specific functionality.

```
c = (k + p) % 25
```

Wrong! You always perform a modular calculation with the same size as the alphabet. This might work as well (if you forget about the `Z`) but it's not Vigenere as it was written down a long time ago.

```
alphaPlaintextFileObj.close()
```

Always close files as soon as they are not necessary any more. You already read all of the plaintext, no need to keep that file handle around.

---

What I'm missing is validation that the contents of the plaintext consist of characters that are out of range, and a way of handling those. The same thing goes for the key, which should consist of all uppercase characters, but lowercase characters are used without issue.

---

Furthermore, if you take a good look, then decryption is the same as encryption, except for `p = (c - k) % 25` and - of course - the file handling. Now the file reading and writing should not be in either method, so let's exclude that. That leaves us with that single assignment / expression. Of that, only the `-` sign is really different.

This is why most people will write a single "private" `_crypt` method that simply takes an integer of `1` for encryption and `-1` for decryption. Then the expression becomes `(charIndex + direction * keyIndex) % alphabetSize`.

Currently you are violating the "DRY principle": don't repeat yourself.